# Dequeue scripts and styles only for specific custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

I am trying to dequeue some scripts and styles only for specific custom post type. But when I add this snippet of code the actions are applied for the entire website as the styles and the scripts are dequeued for all other post types and pages where I need them. Thanks in advance!

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_my_scripts', 999 );
function dequeue_my_scripts()
{
  if ( 'guide' == get_post_type() )
     wp_dequeue_script( 'dw_focus' );
     wp_dequeue_script( 'comment-reply' );
     wp_dequeue_style( 'style' );
     wp_dequeue_style( 'responsive' );
}
```

Comment: try debugging with `var_dump(get_post_type());`

Comment: added `var_dump(get_post_type( 'guide' ));` below the `{` and **bool(false)** appeared on the very top of every of website's pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `{...}` around the calls to `wp_dequeue_script`. That means only the first one is associated with the `if` statement, and the rest are being executed for every case.

Update your code to the following:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_my_scripts', 999 );
function dequeue_my_scripts()
{
    if ( 'guide' == get_post_type() )
    { 
        wp_dequeue_script( 'dw_focus' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'comment-reply' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'style' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'responsive' );
    } 
}
```